# camel route test - the registry for: mock:result

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I have complex camel route and in between the route I am sending mesage to MQ using Bean.

```
.bean("{{tp.mqservice}}")
```

> application.yaml

```
   mqservice: bean:mqService
```

> application-test.yaml

```
mqservice: mock:result
```

> Below is my PortfolioRouteTest

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@MockEndpoints
public class PortfolioTncRouteTest {

    @EndpointInject(value = "{{trade-publisher.portfolio-tnc.source-endpoint}}")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @EndpointInject(value = "{{trade-publisher.mqservice}}")
    private MockEndpoint mock;
}
```

> Junit

```
@Test
public void portfolioTncRouteTest() throws InterruptedException {
    data = ...
    Mockito.when(service.search(Mockito.any(....class))).thenReturn(...);
    producerTemplate.sendBody(data);
    mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mock.assertIsSatisfied(30000);
}
```

however when I run the test I am getting below error. Am I missing something?

> Stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: mock:result
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.getBean(RegistryBean.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.createCacheHolder(RegistryBean.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.BeanReifier.createProcessor(BeanReifier.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessorImpl(ProcessorReifier.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:415)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ExpressionReifier.createFilterProcessor(ExpressionReifier.java:39)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.WhenReifier.createProcessor(WhenReifier.java:32)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.WhenReifier.createProcessor(WhenReifier.java:24)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ChoiceReifier.createProcessor(ChoiceReifier.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessorImpl(ProcessorReifier.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:415)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.TryReifier.createProcessor(TryReifier.java:38)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessorImpl(ProcessorReifier.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:415)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createChildProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:231)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.SplitReifier.createProcessor(SplitReifier.java:42)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorReifier.java:536)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:241)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.addRoutes(RouteReifier.java:358)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.to` instead of `.bean` so its sending to a Camel endpoint, then you can send to the mock endpoint. When using `.bean` then its for calling a POJO Java bean only.